# Рекурсия с условиями, на основе массива данных

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня формируется некая схема, по которой я хочу пройтись циклом и выполнить опеределённые условия для определённых операторов.

```
const arrWhereScheme = [{
  operator: 'and',
  item: [{
    method: 'eq',
    condition: {'name': 'Имя}
  }, {
    method: 'in',
    condition: {'count': [1,2,3]}
  }, {
    operator: 'or',
    item: [{
      method: 'eq',
      condition: {'name': 'Имя'}
    }, {
      method: 'gt',
      condition: {'startDate': "20.08.2017"}
    }]
  }]
}];
```

Содержимое схемы: объект (может быть много) содержащий поле operator и поля item (является массивом).
Элементы в item могут содержать в себе объект в котором есть поле method и condition, но так же item может содержать в себе повторный объект из 
поля operator и поля item (является массивом) и дальше суть повторяется, такое количество может быть досточно глубоким, но заранее не известно.
Когда подобная схема сформируется, мне необходимо пройтись по ней в цикле, и выполнить условия для нужных операторов.
В данном объекте есть operator который будет вызывать опеределённый блок кода, а так же количество элементов.

```
arrWhereScheme.forEach(items => (
  if(items.operator === 'and'){
    item.item.forEach((inItem)=> (
      // Здесь будут выполняться условия если элементы содержат method и condition, 
      // но если появился объект с полем operator и item, то повторить конструкицю
      if(items.operator === 'and'){
        item.item.forEach((inItem)=> ()) 
      }
    ))
  }
  // Здесь конечно возможен не один if
));
```

Как реализовать такую рекурсию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arrWhereScheme = [/*...*/]; 
processScheme(arrWhereScheme); 

function processScheme(schm) {
  /* <тут switch (operator), и т.д.> */
  schm.forEach(item => {
    /* <тут какая-то работа с method и condition item'ов> */
    if (item.operator)   // или if (item.item)
      processScheme(item); 
  }); 
}
```

---

***Оффтоп:***
Если свойство-массив `item` у элементов первого уровня схемы всегда присутствует (независимо от значения `operator`), то логичнее вынести перебор этого свойства за пределы `if` или `case` - для DRY и повышения читаемости кода.

То есть,

- действия при разных значениях `operator` оформить функциями (для удобства можно засунуть их в объект, где ключами являются значения `operator`)
- в кейсах `switch (operator)` помещать ссылку на нужную функцию в переменную, скажем `func`. А если сделано объектом, то необходимость в ветвлении вовсе отпадает:
  `func = opFunctions[schm.operator];`
- далее из переменнной и вызывать, типа
  `func(item.method, item.condition);`

Еще можно `map`'ить массив `item` в массив результатов, затем передавая его аргументом в функцию оператора... так не придется хранить промежуточные результаты. Ведь в любом случае проверяются все элементы `item` (и по-моему, это неоптимально), так как работу `forEach` нельзя прервать кроме как исключением.

Методы (обработку элементов `condition`) желательно так же оформить отдельными функциями. В общем, тут само собой напрашивается объектное решение: это позволит держать всю логику в одном месте (в объекте и его методах), при этом не создавая единую "монстр-функцию" парсинга, или целый ворох хелперов (все это будет сложно поддерживать, а объектную реализацию - легко. К тому же, решение на объектах и прототипах это "JS-way").